# Computation of $H^∗ (Σ\mathbb RP^n , \mathbb F_2)$ as graded $\mathbb F_2$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, cw-complexes

I'm trying to compute
$H^*(\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{F}_2)$
as a $\mathbb{F}_2$ graded algebra. I know that the cup product is 0 since since it is for all suspensions, but I'm not sure how to use that or how to start.I'm trying to compute $H^1(\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{F}_2)$ and I think I should use properties of the suspension but I don't know them.

I have an answer but no way to know if this is true

I'm stuck and I don't know which direction to take some hints would help a lot!

Thanks !

**Edit: **

I have used mayer vietoris for all degrees above 1 but I dont know how to compute degress 0 and 1 cans someone help ?

Comment: The suspension $\Sigma X$ is a union of two cones $CX$ glued along along the common copy of $X$. Try setting up Mayer-Vietoris like that.

Comment: @Thorgott this helps a lot thanks, I think that the problem is that I'm not sure I understand what more I should do to compute it as a graded algebra

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting to give for this problem? If you can compute the graded vector space structure and you know the product structure, what more do you want?

Comment: And another one of these questions that remain unanswered because the comment section has been abused for posting answers ... Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer thanks to the comments:

Write $\mathbb{R}P^n=X$ and $\Sigma X= X_- \cup X_+$ where $X_-$, $ X_+$ are two cones and their intersection is $X$ now we use Mayer Vietoris to get :

$$... \to H^{n-1}(X_-)\oplus H^{n-1}(X_+) \to H^{n-1}(X)\to H^{n}(\Sigma X)\to H^{n}(X_-)\oplus H^{n}(X_+) \to ...$$

Since $X_-$, $ X_+$  are cones, they are contractible hence $H^{n-1}(X_-)\oplus H^{n-1}(X_+)=0$ for all $n$ ( we work with reduced cohomology) so we get an isomorphism $H^{n-1}(X) \simeq H^{n}(\Sigma X)$.